# How do I use Tortoise HG to set up a repository on my computer?

Tags: mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

I was given the company website for our repository on a new project, but I don't know how to set up the repository on my computer using Tortoise HG. Our previous project was already set up on my machine when I started working so I didn't need to know how. I would feel more comfortable asking this community rather than my boss.

The repository is a "Mercurial repository". The website itself is set up in this way.
[image]
I've downloaded the files from the "zip" button, but don't know how to connect that file to the website using Tortoise so things I do will actually affect the real repository.

**How do I set up the Tortoise workbench so that I can pull and push changes to the repository?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zip contains only the files without any of the mercurial specific part. You can delete it, we won't use it to setup your personal repository.

First of all you need to have the URL to access your repository. Depending on the configuration of the server, it can be through HTTP, SSH or even a network share. Then you will eventually need credentials.

You can look for a "clone" URL somewhere on the website or ask a coworker / your boss for this.

Once you have the URL, you simply clone the repository with TortoiseHG : http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.9/clone.html

You can now use your repository like the precedant one.

Comment: Got it set up, thank you so much! Much easier than I feared it would be.